# Hyphen and/or period in environment variable name is causing issue

Tags: openshift, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise

This is working.

```
oc new-app --docker-image=docker.mycompany.com/myusername/my-imagestuff:latest -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL="jdbc:sqlserver://blahblahblah;” -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=“myUserName1” -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=“MyP#ssword” -e
```

so I went back and added the datasource-classname

```
oc new-app --docker-image=docker.mycompany.com/myusername/my-imagestuff:latest -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL="jdbc:sqlserver://blahblahblah;” -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=“myUserName1” -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=“MyP#ssword” -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
```

and now my deployments are failing with this error:

> error: invalid parameter assignment in
>   "SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

**What is the magic sauce of hyphen / hyphens and/or periods / dots in the environment variable and value
?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're unable to use environment variables that contain hyphens or periods because those characters are not valid in shell variable names:

```
➜  tmp.0ngsgXro foo.bar=1
   zsh: command not found: foo.bar=1

➜  tmp.0ngsgXro foo-bar=1
   zsh: command not found: foo-bar=1

➜  tmp.0ngsgXro foo_bar=1
➜  tmp.0ngsgXro echo $foo_bar
   1
```

You're trying to create an environment variable in your container that violates the rules of the underlying shell.

Answer (score 0):

So out of desperation, I changed the hyphens to underscores.

Note the last argument of SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME

```
oc new-app --docker-image=docker.mycompany.com/myusername/my-imagestuff:latest -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL="jdbc:sqlserver://blahblahblah;” -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=“myUserName1” -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=“MyP#ssword” -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
```

And my app is working.  So I am writing this answer.

I do not understand this voodoo.

If someone can explain it, I'd be grateful.